# When I made call through SIP phone, the mobile number edit into my dialed call log that I want to clear, how can I do that?

Tags: android, dialog, sip, calllog

I have done the following changes into my code. I just want to clear the call log that written by the SIP phone, I have made my SIP phone using SIPDROID.
If I delete the permissions from Android manifest it gives me an error.
All I want is to remove the dialed call logs into the recent calling history.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        Log.e("Test", "Back button pressed!");
    }
    else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
        Log.e("Test", "Home button pressed!");
        onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```